# R plot not adding plot colors as per documentation?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

So I am using a simple dataframe for plotting which looks like:

```
Category    x
<chr>   <dbl>
2018    2568907
2019    5600309
2020    7488549
```

And the code I am trying is:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Category, y=x)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"))
p
```

But no matter whether I add scale_color_manual or not, all the bars are shown of same color. However according to [documentation](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-barplots-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization) I am following, it should be of different colors.

Comment: You didn’t nap anything to color or fill in your aes() so those scales will never be used. You need a mapping first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding a fill or color statement to `aes()` and then use `scale_fill_*()` or `scale_color_*()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(df, aes(x=Category, y=x,fill=Category)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"))
```